# How to ignore leading whitespace in XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I need to load xml from a file into an XmlDocument. The problem is that the file contains some leading whitespace. (I have no control over the system that produces the file.)
Is there any clean/easy way to ignore or strip those characters?

```
string SamplelRequestFile = @"C:\example.xml";
XmlDocument docXML = new XmlDocument(); 
XmlTextReader xReader = new XmlTextReader(SamplelRequestFile);
XmlReaderSettings ReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
ReaderSettings.XmlResolver = null;
ReaderSettings.ProhibitDtd = false;
docXML.Load(xReader);
```

example.xml (note the leading spaces)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<myRoot>
<someElement />
</myRoot>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll just have to do something like

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\example.xml"))
 {
      XmlDocument docXML = new XmlDocument(); 
      docXML.LoadXml(sr.ReadToEnd().Trim());
      ...
 }
```

Comment: This will work, but only for smaller documents.  If you start processing very large documents, you will run into problems.  A possible solution is to create a new Stream type reads the XML file and simply refuses to return characters until it finds the first non-whitespace character in the feed.

Comment: Another option is to try treating the document as an XML fragment, the XmlTextReader might be more forgiving:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakk7ha0.aspx

Comment: This will only work if the XML file is UTF-8 encoded as ReadToEnd reads in UTF-8 by default.

Answer (score 4):

here is a sample that works:

```
        string file = @"C:\example.xml";
        XmlDocument docXML = new XmlDocument();
        using (TextReader x = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            while (x.Peek() == ' ')
                x.Read();
            docXML.Load(x);
        }
```

Comment: this is the best solution IMHO

Comment: I like this answer also, but am using a more generic test for whitespace which worked better for the files I was encountering.
`while (char.IsWhiteSpace((char)x.Peek()))`

Answer (score 3):

This is an **invalid XML**.

According to XML Specification, **pi** or **processing-instructions** must be the first characters if they are present.

I suggest you pre-process the XML by *trimming* the XML.

---

## Workaround:

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\example.xml");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(content.Trim());
```

Comment: Yes, I know that this is invalid XML. But that's precisely the problem that needs to be addressed.

Comment: The problem is, this limits the size of XML that can be processed by the amount of memory available.  If you've got one of those 2gb XML files, you've just crashed out the system.  You might not have control of your feeds but they're not sending XML, you need to get them to fix it.

Comment: Good point about huge files. Regarding 'get them to fix it', the conversation might go like this: Hello Billion Dollar Corporation? I'd like to speak with someone in the We've Always Done It This Way Department. Sure, I'll hold...  ;-)

Comment: Fair enough :)  In the mean time, like I suggested above, creating your own stream that simply omits any whitespace characters at the start of a request might do the trick...

Comment: Again, this will only work if the XML file is UTF-8 encoded as ReadAllText reads in UTF-8 by default.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Stream` and a `StreamReader` on the file yourself, then `Peek()` and consume characters from the stream as long as you see whitespace. Once you're sure that the next character is `<`, pass the stream to the `XmlTextReader` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this flag ?

```
ReaderSettings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
```

Comment: Yes, but that only applies to the XML once it's read in. In this case, the whitespace prevents the data from being recognized as readable XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
string newXml = string.TrimLeft(oldXml);
```